# Is it possible to get the associated object that triggered a callback in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have a Content Object that has many Posts, with attributes on the Post object delegated to Content. So that when I edit a Post and save it, it goes to update the associated Content object which in turn goes to update all other Posts that might be tied to it as well, what I'm trying to avoid is a situation where the post that set off the update callback on content gets updated in the Content callback as well. Is that possible?

```
class Content > ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
    after_save :update_posts
    def update_posts
        #I'd like to make sure the post that kicked off the save doesn't get reindexed here
        self.posts.each{|x| x.update_search_index}
    end
end

class Post > ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :Content
    after_save :update_content, :update_search_index

    def save_content
        self.content.save #this kicks off an aftersave callback on content that winds up recalling update_search_index, I'm trying to avoid that
    end

    def update_search_index
      #persist post to search index
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you please post the necessary code from Content and Post models?

Comment: yup code would be helpful +1 , without that it will be like shhoting the dark

Comment: This is a made up scenario, but I just posted something that I think models the problem I'm trying to solve